# is a "where in" clause with 1000 parts too much

Tags: mysql, database-design

If i want to create a page of status/message updates for a particular entity, is there a better way to do it than this:

1. get all entities you follow/subscribe to
2. perform WHERE IN on status table.

My concern is: what if you follow 1000, 2000 entities? is that a problem? whats the optimal way of doing this kind of data retrieval?

Comment: You could let the database do both steps without a round-trip by doing a subquery. That might also let the database engine optimize it more somehow.

Comment: Oracle, specifically, limits and `IN` clause to 1000 elements. This is much better done by tables and JOINs

Comment: I agree with the JOIN (perhaps implicitly written as a subquery). Besides relevant hard-limits, many database implementations have "optimal" limits on the number of values that can be supplied to `IN` before performance degrades.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is (probably) not a good one. Generally speaking, WHERE IN is only good when the number of terms is small and constant.

Most WHERE IN clauses can be converted to joins, and this sounds no different.
Try this (guessing schema):

```
SEKECT s.*
FROM followed f
JOIN status s ON s.entity_id = f.entity_id
WHERE f.user_id = ?
```

Coding it like this will give good performance, as long as you have indexes on `followed(user_id)` and `status(entity_id)`

Comment: I agree with all the suggestions to use a join.  Not sure if there was a reason why I didn't use it.  However, this leads me to another question.  Do you know of a way/strategy to optimize the status/message retrieval? The page would be paginated, and the i'd only be interested in the most recent items.

Comment: Just do a ORDER BY and LIMIT on the query.

Comment: In your example when the status table grows, the query takes a while to run ( 1.3 + seconds, in test table with 200,000 rows, to get 20+ rows ).  I have and index on the id columns.

Comment: @bohemian You say WHERE IN is only good when the number of terms is small. Where's your reference for that? I would like to read some benchmarks or case studies that support this claim.

Comment: @AntonioMax I have no links. I have only 20 years experience. It would be easy to construct a test for this. I suggest you do that post back your findings. Surely google yields info too.

Comment: @Bohemian I have to match (maybe a few times a day) something like a thousand IDS that aren't in my DB with IDs I have in my DB, so I was searching for references on using WHERE field IN (large CSV id list). Care to give me some alternatives then?

Comment: If its only a few times a day, performance doesn't matter - do what ever is easiest.